# Failed at the dlib-build@0.1.1 install

Tags: python, node.js, npm, cmake, face-recognition

My computer os is windows,
I downloaded the cmake on this url https://cmake.org/download/ after than i create a folder on my desktop for my project. my folder name is "first-face-recognition".
After than i install OpenBLAS on this website https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/ after than i copy the folder of opeblas in to my project folder.

i run this codes on the cmd ;

```
cd /Desktop/first-face-recognition
npm install face-recognition
```

I get this error ;

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dlib-build@0.1.1 install: `node ./install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dlib-build@0.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\homiko\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-23T19_37_56_235Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Is there any more to the error? If so, can you post the whole thing please?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error and the problem was that i did not have installed `cmake`. So, in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cmake
```

did the job. Note that installation error didn't mention anything about `cmake`.
Hope it helps.